# Multicollinearity and its effects

Tags: machine-learning

1.Can some intuitively explain me what to do when we have multicollinearity in our data.

2. Which ML algorithms are insensitive to multicollinearity?
3. When there is a need to perform the standardisation in the problem?
4. Are there any simple ways to detect the multicollinearity?

Please answer the above questions.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you met this program in some kind of regression.

1. If perfect multicollinearity, drop the covariates/independent varaibles. If partial multicollinearity there are many ways to deal with it.
2. All of the algorithm involving $(X'X)^{-1}$ are sensitive to multicollinearity.
3. Standardization has no any help on perfect multicollinearity.
4. Eigenvalues and the indexes derived from  eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you explain your second point in detail?

Comment: Like $1/y$ if $y=0$ then $1/y$ does not exist. Similarly, if $X$ is  perfect collinearity, $(X'X)^{-1}$ does not exist. If $y = 0.0000001$  the result of $1/y$ is very sensitive to the tiny change on $y$. Similarly, $(X'X)^{-1}$ is sensitive to tiny change on $X$ if $X$ has severe collinearity problem ($X'X$ has very small eigenvalue)